# How to get url of file after uploading to document library?

Tags: client-object-model, sandbox-solution, file-upload

How do you return the URL of a file after it has been uploaded to a document library, using the default upload page? Returning the text from the "inputFile" textbox from the upload.aspx page would also work, but I can't figure out how to do that because it's loaded inside a modal dialog.

```
function uploadPicture(){
var currentUserDispName ='myname';
var options = {
    url: '/test/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List=6c7bc1b3%2D1b7f%2D466b%2Da0f5%2Dac15dc334ff7& RootFolder=/test/mydocs/' +      currentUserDispName + "&IsDlg=1",
    width: 450,
    height: 230,
    title: 'Upload a Picture',
    dialogReturnValueCallback: function(result, returnValue) {

    if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
          //get File URL
    } 
    else {                     
    //else
   }
    }; SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build the URL to the item through JavaScript?

It appears you have all the components (like URL to the current site/subsite, document library, folder, and filename).

Comment: The problem is I can't get the filename to build the URL.